# When using NextJS 13 API route, how can I validate the header of a request using Zod?

Tags: validation, next.js, request, zod

I am writing NextJS 13 (app router variant) API GET endpoint.

I need to validate the value of the 'identifier' header that is sent in the request to ensure that it is a string.

However, it's failing validation (responds with the 400 status below), even though I know for sure that the request does contain an 'identifier' header and it does, in fact, have a value which is a string.

```
const requestSchema = z.object( {
  headers: z.object({
    identifier: z.string(),
  }),
});

const parsedRequest = requestSchema.safeParse(req);

if (!parsedRequest.success)
  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({
      errorCode: "badRequest",
    }),

    {
      status: 400,
    }
  );
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can use Zod to validate headers (and, also URL params)?